# What does the -V indicate on MKC ticker

Tags: stocks

McCormick & Co. Inc. shows two symbols,on a Yahoo lookup. What's the difference?

Answer (score 3):

**MKC** is non-voting stock, **MKC/V** is voting stock.

Ofter times you'll see two or more stock symbols for a company.  These usually reflect different [classes of stocks](http://www.investopedia.com/university/stocks/stocks2.asp).  For example, voting vs. non-voting (as in this case) or preferred vs non-preferred stock.